# Notifcation Android from Service Firebase can update and not open the pending Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with my notification. In my app, I use Firebase. I call notification every get message. But I have problem:

- Notification does not update Title and Content Text.
- Pending Intent does not open the target Activity

This my Notification Code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                int action = json.getInt(Sample.ACTION);
                if(action==1){
                    String order = json.getString(Sample.ORDER);
                   sendNotification(order);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String order) {

        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Bundle args= new Bundle();
        args.putString(Sample.ORDER, order);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgressOrderActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtras(args);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri =  Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.fishtank_bubbles);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("NEW ORDER. GET NOW !!!")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification noti = notificationBuilder.build();
        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }

}
```

please how to solve it , or any mistakes from my code ?